# Probability of meeting of two people

Tags: probability

The probability that two friends will be able to meet each other between 9:00am and 12:00 noon, not waiting for each other for more than 15 minutes is?

Comment: @TheDeadLegend That's, uh, one hour. This one is three hours. Nevertheless the solution follows the same lines.

Comment: Could not understand it.. Can anyone help me in a bit simpler manner

Comment: Let $U,V$ denote iid random variables with standard uniform distribution (which is actually a preassumption), and let $9+3U,9+3V$ be the arrival times. Then you are asked to find $\Pr(|(9+3U)-(9+3V)|\leq\frac14)=\Pr(|U-V|\leq\frac1{12})$.